# number of subsets of a set with even sum using combinatorics or binomial

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let S={a1,a2,a3.......aN}.There are 2^N subsets of this set so if we don't consider the empty set we are left with 2^N-1.We do need to consider cases where it number of odd numbers may be zero and number of odd numbers not zero.How do we count the number of subsets of this set having sum as even?

Answer (score 5):

Let $o$ and $e$ be the number of odd and even numbers in $S$, respectively, with $o+e=N$. If $o=0$, all $2^N$ subsets have even sum. If $o\ne0$, then half of the $2^o$ subsets of the odd numbers contain an even number of odd numbers and hence have an even sum, and they can be combined with all $2^e$ subsets of the even numbers, for a total of $2^{e+o-1}=2^{N-1}$ subsets.

Comment: Don't forget to subtract the empty set at the end (it was not to be included in the final count if I understood the question correctly).

Comment: @Arthur: Both the title and the last sentence of the question ask for the number of subsets having even sum, without restriction. Since the OP can simply enough subtract $1$ from the result, the remark about the total number of non-empty sets in the middle of the question didn't seem to warrant complicating things unduly :-)

Comment: You're right, I might be reading too much into that one sentence. @user327488 Note that the empty subset has an even sum (that sum is $0$). Many people find this very strange and nonsensical at first, but it is convention, and it makes a surprising amount of sense.